# how to unhide the letters in this game?

Tags: python

it's a guess-the-letter game something like hangman. it generates a random word in the length of 4 or 5 it's the user's choice and after that, it displays it like this ^^^^ for 4 letters for example. each time user can guess a letter if it's not right I display a message and says it but if it's right has to display that it is right and display the word something for example like this ^a^^. the letter has to be exactly in the position of the original word. can someone help me with the part where the letter that is guessed is right? How shoul i code that this format ^^^^ be forexample like ^a^^ if the letter guessed is right?

```
# Choosing the words
if result2 == 4:
    word = choice(word4)
else:
    word = choice(word5)
guess_list = []  # List of guess letters
sec_word = []  # the list for formatting the random word
for i in range(len(word)):
    sec_word.append("*")  # To format the random word into ****
while result1 > 0:  # Start of the guessing game on the condition that guess left is greater than 0
    print("word is:", "".join(sec_word))  # Displaying the word
    # Displaying the remaining guess number
    print("Guess remaining:", num_guess)
    print("Previous guess:", guess)  # Showing the previous guest
    guess = input("Please guess a letter: ")
    guess_list.append(guess)  # Add the guess letters to a list
    if guess.lower() == "stop" or guess.lower() == "exit":
        print("Game Ends!")
        break  # Letting user end the game at anytime
    if guess not in guess_list:
        if guess in word:  # if the user guess correct letter
            print(guess, "is in the word")
        else:  # if the user guess wrong letter
            print("Sorry! letter entered is not present in the word!")
    else:
        # If a letter is already in list
        print("You have already guessed that letter, Try another letter")
    result1 -= 1  # After each guess the remaining guess time drops 1 time
```

and output of the code is supposed to be something like this

```
Word is: ****
Guesses remaining: 6
Previous Guesses: 
Choose a letter to guess: a
‘a’ is NOT in the word! Try again!
Word is: ****
Guesses remaining: 5
Previous Guesses: a
Choose a letter to guess: b
‘b’ is in the word!
Word is: b***
Guesses remaining: 4
Previous Guesses: a
Choose a letter to guess: l
‘l’ is in the word!
Word is: bl**
Guesses remaining: 3
Previous Guesses: a
Choose a letter to guess: a
‘a’ is NOT in the word and has been guessed before.
Guesses remaining: 3
Choose another letter to guess: e
‘e’ is in the word!
Word is: bl*e
Guesses remaining: 2
Previous Guesses: a
Choose a letter to guess: exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this base code will work for this,
Note: You need to find index of all occurrences if character is present more than twice in word ( ex: pool ) here o is occurring twice, so you can loop over the base method to replace both occurrences

```
original_word = 'avatar'
masked_word = '*' * len(original_word)

i = 4 # this is index of character

if(i == 0):
    masked_word = original_word[0] + masked_word[1:]
elif(i == len(original_word)-1):
    masked_word = masked_word[:i] + original_word[i]
else:
    masked_word = masked_word[:i] + original_word[i] + masked_word[i+1:]

print(masked_word)
```